# Modpack crashes by generating and entering a world

Tags: minecraft-modding

My own Modpack is chrashing every time I want to generate a new world or want to enter an existing (from older versions or vanilla) I getting this error:

```
The game crashed whilst exception in server tick loop
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void net.minecraft.server.level.DistanceManager.addRegionTicket(net.minecraft.server.level.TicketType, net.minecraft.world.level.ChunkPos, int, java.lang.Object, boolean)'
Exit-Code: -1
```

the crash log is here: https://gist.github.com/opensource25/f6773df862fd5f313134e56f8c4f608f

Could someone help me fixing this error so I can play my Modpack?

Comment: To get help debugging a problem, it's customary to share a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the code that causes the problem. The call site where you invoke addRegionTicket looks like a useful thing to include. You may also want to search for your error message - doing so turns up this [forum thread, which suggests disabling Optifine or down-grading to an earlier version of Forge may help](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/113612-my-minecraft-keeps-crashing-when-at-1-while-loading-worlds/).

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` means something is trying to use a method that doesn't exist. Assuming that's the root cause, it could be the result of a typo (spelled the method name wrong), an error in the parameters being passed, or a version discrepancy (the method was valid on a prior version). It's possible for one error to mask another though, so `NoSuchMethodError` might be a symptom of an earlier problem.

Comment: If I'm reading the crash log correctly, you're loading dozens of mods. As part of building a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE), remove as many unnecessary mods as possible. You can slowly add them back in once you're done troubleshooting, but for the purposes of debugging, you want things as stripped down as possible. The log flagged numerous mods as `incompatible` - that's another thing I would be very critical of.

Comment: Can you clarify: is one of these mods one that you have created yourself? What we help with is creating new games and mods. Questions about *playing* games/mods are usually for [our sister site Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), but they have a rule saying that [*modded* Minecraft troubleshooting is not on-topic there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See their [guide for where to get help with Minecraft mods](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13559/where-can-i-ask-technical-troubleshooting-questions-about-modded-minecraft) if that's what you need.